# Biztalk 2010 odx.cs file

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk-2009

Are there generated .cs files for Biztalk 2010 orchestrations, and if so where are they located? In Biz 09 they were File0.cs but I haven't been able to find any odx.cs or .cs files that correspond to orchestrations for my Biz 2010 projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just checked some old BTS 2009 projects and there aren't any .cs files in the same directory as the source .odx either. Maps (`.btm.cs`), Schemas (`.xsd.cs`), Pipelines (`.btp.cs`) do have generated .cs files in the source folder.

However, in both BTS 2009 and 2010, files are placed in the `obj\Debug\BizTalk\XLang` folder, but are renamed `File0.cs, File1.cs` etc. Reference [here](http://www.businessprocessintegration.net/2009/09/how-to-debug-an-orchestration-in-biztalk-server-2009/)

Out of interest, why do you want to view the .odx.cs files?

Comment: Aha! Thanks, I was looking in the wrong directory. My main interest in looking at these is to try to debug orchestration errors like "Errors exist for one or more children." Or figure out how such an error comes up...